# Typescript generic map return value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a method that returns an `Object` which I use as a map to arrays of strings.
My problem is that I don't know how to define the return value using generics for type safety.
I thought about adding a new interface or class to represent a map, but I'd like to avoid that, given that `Object` itself is already a map.

Here's some example code that should shed some light on the problem:

```
getMap() : Object {
  return {
    1: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
    2: [ 'd', 'e' ],
    3: [ ]
  }
}
```

I'd like to be able to define the return value of the method so that it's clear that it's a map of `String[]` or `Array<String>`, without the need to implement an artificially added `Map` interface.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: How about `{ [key: number]: string[] }`? Also it is recommended to use `object`/`string` (lowercase),  explanation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html)

Comment: @AlekseyL. , I've been using number, boolean and string in all lowercase (didn't know why at the time), just Object stuck with me (probably from Java ...). I wasn't aware of this syntax as I'm new to TypeScript. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @AlekseyL. what about Array<String> vs. String[] ? Same thing ? Is that for boxing as well ?

Comment: You're welcome! Regarding Array vs [] - there's no difference (as it not primitive), so `Array<string>` is the same as `string[]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like @Aleksey commented, `{ [key: number]: string [] }` would do the job.

Further, there is a builtin type alias `Record` actually represents a map. `{ [key: number]: string[] }` is equal to `Record<number, string[]>`. And if you want to support string keys as well, the type would be `Record<number | string, string[]>`.